# Sorting multiple arrays of different types from a read file

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, visual-c++, bubble-sort

I'm working on a program that mimics an "Animal Adoption Agency." I read from the file, which contains a list of animal names, breed, age, price, and sex. I have two files, one each for cats and dogs.

The user has an option to sort the list by the above listed categories. I have a for loop currently that will accurately sort the category they choose; however, the other categories will not order themselves accordingly. I'm not sure how to go about this.
Here's a condensed version of my code, that allows access only to the dogs portion and sorting by name, rather than have a choice of how to sort.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <istream>
    #include <cctype>
    #include <string>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>
    using namespace std;

    int animalMenu, animalCount, animAge[50], animPrice[50], entry = 0, total;
    string animType, animName[50], animBreed[50], animSex[50], takeHomeWith;
    ifstream animalInform;
    const int WIDTH = 8, BIG_WIDTH = 12;

    void sortingHat(string[]);
    void innerSorting(string[], int);

    int main() {
            animalInform.open("Dog Information.txt");
            animType = "dogs";

            // SET NUMBER OF ANIMALS IN FILE
            animalInform >> animalCount;
            cout << "There are " << animalCount << " " << animType << "! \n";

            // SETS ALL THE VALUES BY READING FROM FILE
            for (int entry = 0; entry < animalCount; entry++) {
                animalInform >> animName[entry] >> animBreed[entry] >> animAge[entry] >> animPrice[entry] >> animSex[entry];
                cout << setw(BIG_WIDTH) << animName[entry] << setw(BIG_WIDTH) << animBreed[entry] << setw(WIDTH) << animAge[entry] << setw(WIDTH) << animPrice[entry] << setw(WIDTH) << animSex[entry] << endl;
            }
           // CLOSE FILE
            animalInform.close();

           // CALL FUNCTION TO SORT (BY NAME ONLY)
            sortingHat(animName);
            cout << endl;   
            // DISPLAY NEWLY SORTED LIST
            for (int entry = 0; entry < animalCount; entry++) {
                cout << setw(BIG_WIDTH) << animName[entry] << setw(BIG_WIDTH) << animBreed[entry] << setw(WIDTH) << animAge[entry] << setw(WIDTH) << animPrice[entry] << setw(WIDTH) << animSex[entry] << endl;
            }
            system("pause");
    }

    void sortingHat(string sortingString[])
    { // SORTS DATA AND PUTS IT IN ORDER, ALPHABETICAL -- 
        for (int outer = 0; outer <= animalCount; outer++)
        {
            for (int entry = 0; entry <= (animalCount - 2); entry++) {
                string temporary[50];
                if (sortingString[entry] > sortingString[entry + 1])
                    innerSorting(sortingString, entry);
            }
        }
    }

    void innerSorting(string sorter[], int entry)
    {
        string temporary[50];
        temporary[entry] = sorter[entry];
        sorter[entry] = sorter[entry + 1];
        sorter[entry + 1] = temporary[entry];
    }
```

So I obviously don't have anything that would make the other entries follow suit.
So if I choose name to be sorted, my output (this is what is written in my file) will go from

```
Brienne Shepard 6 $150 F
Jon Labrador 3 $200 M
Aemon ShihTzu 10 $50 M
```

to

```
Aemon Shepard 6 $150 F
Brienne Labrador 3 $200 M
Jon ShihTzu 10 $50 M
```

And I want it to do this (if choosing to sort by name):

```
 Aemon ShihTzu 10 $50 M
 Brienne Shepard 6 $150 F
 Jon Labrador 3 $200 M
```

Comment: Have you used vectors in class?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe no- she did tell us we could use vectors if we wanted though. Would you recommend using those instead of arrays?

Comment: Always.  A `vector<animal> adoptable_animals;` would provide for the simplest solution.  Your sorting condition would then change depending on the sort criteria.

Comment: @Amanda Stone  What is the "list of animal names, breed, age, price, and sex"? How is it defined?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it is a .txt file. It is arranged in the way I show it in the first box, IE. "Name Breed Age Price Sex" , with each different dog on a new line. I have fixed my code so it shows more of the program, if you mean how do I call the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly you have a set of arrays that contain animal characteristics. And you are going to sort by one characteristics such a way that all arrays would be sorted. If so then you can write one common function for all arrays.

For example

```
enum SortType { SortByName, /* other types of sorting */, SortByAge };

//...

void bubble_sort( std::string animName[], 
                  /* other characteristics */ 
                  int animAge[], 
                  size_t n, 
                  SortType type )
{
    for ( size_t last; not ( n < 2 ); n = last )
    {
        for ( size_t i = last = 1; i < n; i++ )
        {
            bool less = false;
            switch ( type )
            {
            case SortByName:
                less = animName[i] < animName[i-1];
                break;
            /* other cases */
            case SortByAge:
                less = animAge[i] < animAge[i-1];
                break;
            }

            if ( less )
            {
                /* swapping elements of all the arrays */
                last = i;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Take into account that this swap function

```
void innerSorting(string sorter[], int entry)
{
    string temporary[50];
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    temporary[entry] = sorter[entry];
    sorter[entry] = sorter[entry + 1];
    sorter[entry + 1] = temporary[entry];
}
```

should not use an array of strings. It can be written like

```
void innerSorting(string sorter[], size_t entry)
{
    string temporary;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    temporary = sorter[entry];
    sorter[entry] = sorter[entry + 1];
    sorter[entry + 1] = temporary;
}
```